# Перестановки и расчет их количества в С

Tags: c

Назовем равномерным набор натуральных чисел, в котором чередуются четные и нечетные числа: четное-нечетное-четное-нечетное... или нечетное-четное-нечетное... Задан набор из 2N натуральных чисел, из которых ровно N чисел четных и N чисел нечетных. Нужно определить, за какое МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ количество перестановок его можно сделать равно мерным. Перестановкой считаем обмен местами двух эл-тов. входные данные: одно число N, во второй строке 2N чисел, через пробел.
пишу программу для расчета количества минимальных перестановок.

делаю таким методом:

1. Считаем, сколько чётных не на своих местах (=a).

   И сколько нечётных не на своих местах (=b).

Если a≠b, у нас нет N чётных и N нечётных — выводим «неверный набор данных».
А если равны, то для порядка чёт-нечет нужно *a* замен. Для противоположного — *N-a*.
Ответ *min(a, N−a)*. 
Вопрос: как посчитать сколько четных не на своих местах? и сколько нечетных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим случай, когда **на первом месте стоит чётное число**.

Заводим два счётчика: счётчик нечётных (oddCounter) и счётчик чётных (evenCounter).

**Проход по массиву:**

1. Если индекс нечётный, то проверяем этот элемент массива на нечётность. Если этот элемент нечётный, то идём дальше. Иначе, oddCounter++.

   Если индекс чётный, то проверяем этот элемент массива на чётность. Если этот элемент чётный, то идём дальше. Иначе, evenCounter++.

Вот и посчитали то, что вы просили. oddCounter - количество нечётных, которые не на своих местах. evenCounter - количество чётных, которые не на своих местах.

А вообще, посчитав какой-нибудь один из них, можно вычислить сколько чисел другого типа не на своём месте.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже сегодня пытался решить эту задачу и благодаря вашей идее "считать количество чисел не на своем месте" у меня получилось. Было бы хорошо, если вы объяснили, как пришли к этой идее.)

Вот мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, num, temp, result1=0, result2=0, result=0;
    cin >> n;
    num = n*2;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        cin >> temp;
        if((temp%2==0&&i%2==0)||(temp%2!=0&&i%2!=0)) result1++;
        else result2++;
    }
    result = result1>result2 ? result2/2 : result1/2;
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Просто совет на будущее: названия переменным стоит давать такие, чтобы кто-то кроме вас понимал о чём речь.

Comment: @LEQADA, всё нормально с именами.